# How can I use BoofCV to transform a list of vertices so that the center of the polygon they form will be moved to the middle of the image?

Tags: java, center, polygon, boofcv

I'm using the code below to detect shapes and extract a list of vertices for each shape found (stored in the List Vertexes). How can I transform the vertices for a shape to ensure that the shape will be located at the center of the image when I draw the vertices?

done here> VisualizeShapes.drawPolygon(vertexes,true,g2);

Is there a built-in way to do it using BoofCV or does it have to be done manually?

```
/**
 * Fits polygons to found contours around binary blobs.
 */
public static void fitBinaryImage(ImageFloat32 input) 
{
    ImageUInt8 binary = new ImageUInt8(input.width,input.height);
    BufferedImage polygon = new BufferedImage(input.width,input.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // the mean pixel value is often a reasonable threshold when creating a binary image
    double mean = ImageStatistics.mean(input);

    // create a binary image by thresholding
    ThresholdImageOps.threshold(input, binary, (float) mean, true);

    // reduce noise with some filtering
    ImageUInt8 filtered = BinaryImageOps.erode8(binary, 1, null);
    filtered = BinaryImageOps.dilate8(filtered, 1, null);

    // Find the contour around the shapes
    List<Contour> contours = BinaryImageOps.contour(filtered, ConnectRule.EIGHT,null);

    // Fit a polygon to each shape and draw the results
    Graphics2D g2 = polygon.createGraphics();
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

    for( Contour c : contours )
    {
        // Fit the polygon to the found external contour. Note loop = true
        List<PointIndex_I32> vertexes = ShapeFittingOps.fitPolygon(c.external,true,toleranceDist,toleranceAngle,100);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        VisualizeShapes.drawPolygon(vertexes,true,g2);

        // handle internal contours now
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for( List<Point2D_I32> internal : c.internal )
        {
            vertexes = ShapeFittingOps.fitPolygon(internal,true,toleranceDist,toleranceAngle,100);
            //********************************************************************************************************************
            //** how can I transform the vertexes here so that the polygon they form is centered at the middle of the image ? ****
            //********************************************************************************************************************
            VisualizeShapes.drawPolygon(vertexes,true,g2);
        }

        System.out.println(vertexes.toString());
        System.out.println(vertexes.size());

    }

    UtilImageIO.saveImage(polygon, "/Users/m/temp/3_fitbinaryimage.png");

}
```